# Cumulated Count by Week

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

Currently I use MySQL - but migrate to SQL Server soon - so both are for the solution okay!

I have a database schema like (table candidate):

```
ID int PRIMARYKEY
intern date
name varchar(255)
```

Table looks Like:

```
| ID         | intern          |   name    |
+------------+-----------------+-----------+
| 1          |  '2020-01-02'   |   Mike    |
| 42         |  '2020-01-05'   |   Nora    |
| 21         |  '2020-01-08'   |   Iris    |
| 331        |  '2020-01-12'   |   Caro    |
```

And some other columns in that table, that are not relevant.

I want to count all intern-Dates by Week. That works find with that:

```
SELECT 
    WEEK(intern) + 1 AS KW, COUNT(intern) AS counts
FROM 
    epunkt_sourcing.candidate
WHERE 
    WEEK(intern) IS NOT NULL AND YEAR(intern) = 2020
GROUP BY 
    KW
ORDER BY 
    KW;
```

Result is something like that:

```
| KW        | counts          |
+-----------+-----------------+
| 1         |  2              |
| 2         | 19              |
| 3         | 18              |
| 4         | 21              |
```

I want also the cumulated counts by Week, is there a chance to sum the counts?

```
| KW        | counts          | cumulated   |
+-----------+-----------------+-------------+
| 1         |  2              |  2          |
| 2         | 19              | 21          |
| 3         | 18              | 39          |
| 4         | 21              | 60          |
```

Comment: MySQL or SQL Server? You've tagged both?

Comment: I use mysql at the moment - but migrate in the next weeks to sql server - so both are for the solution okay

Comment: *Currently I use MySQL* What version? This is critical for your question.

Comment: ... and provide some sample fiddle (and show desired result for fiddle data, not abstract ones).

Comment: Sorry - It's Version 5.7.21

Comment: Cumulative sum for this MySQL version is implemented using 2 table copies or using user-defined variables. Both methods must be fully rewrited while using in SQL server where `SUM() OVER ()` exists. If you'll migrate to SQL Server - update your MySQL to latest (8.0.19) version.

Comment: PS. Your query does NOT contain ORDER BY clause - so records order is not specified, so "cumulative sum" makes no sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try the below query, Hope it will help:

```
SELECT t.KW, t.counts, @cum_total:=@cum_total + t.counts AS cumulative_sum
    FROM
        ( 
            SELECT WEEK(intern)+1 as KW, count(intern) as counts
                FROM epunkt_sourcing.candidate
            WHERE WEEK(intern) IS NOT NULL AND YEAR(intern) = 2020
            GROUP BY WEEK(intern)
        ) AS t
    JOIN (SELECT @cum_total:=0) r;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this in SQL Server:

```
Declare @t table  (KW int,counts int)

Insert into @t values (1,2),(2,19),(3,18),(4,21)

select *, sum(counts) over (order by kw) as cumulated 
from @t
```

Output:

```
KW  counts  cumulated  
1     2           2  
2     19         21  
3     18         39  
4     21         60
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this ought to work. Not sure if it's the most efficient.

```
    SELECT WEEK(intern)+1 as KW, count(intern) as counts into #tempCount
    from epunkt_sourcing.candidate
    WHERE WEEK(intern) IS NOT NULL AND YEAR(intern) = 2020
    GROUP BY WEEK(intern)

    select
     a.kw
    ,a.counts
    ,sum(b.counts) as cumulated

    from #tempCount a
    inner join #tempCount b on a.kw >= b.kw

    group by a.kw, a.counts
    order by a.kw
```

Please test it and let me know

Answer (score 0):

In MySQL and SQL Server you should be using cumulative sums.  The MySQL version is:

```
SELECT WEEK(intern)+1 as KW, COUNT(*) as counts,
      SUM(COUNT(*)) OVER (ORDER BY MIN(intern)) as cumulative
FROM epunkt_sourcing.candidate
WHERE intern >= '2020-01-01' AND intern < '2021-01-01'
GROUP BY KW
ORDER BY KW;
```

In SQL Server, you would use:

```
SELECT DATE_PART(WEEK, intern)+1 as KW, COUNT(*) as counts,
      SUM(COUNT(*)) OVER (ORDER BY MIN(intern)) as cumulative
FROM epunkt_sourcing.candidate
WHERE intern >= '2020-01-01' AND intern < '2021-01-01'
GROUP BY DATE_PART(WEEK, intern)+1 
ORDER BY KW;
```

Notes:

- The first week might be a partial week, depending on the year.  Weeks start on Mondays, but years can start on any date.
- The comparison for the year uses date inequalities.  This is recommended in both databases.
- Date part functions differ among databases.
- SQL Server does not allow column aliases in the `GROUP BY`.
- Both databases support window functions.  MySQL supports variables but they are now deprecated, so you should not be using them.